# Can't enable Vibrancy Continued in Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AhUF.png)

My laptop is Mac Ventura 13.2.1. I try to install Vibrancy in Mac but once I try to enable it, it reports "Something went wrong: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/private/var/folders/5_/z68nzpys4836v4l79nh8tcz00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/FF3069DD-73FF-4327-A2F5-8C909B8834A0/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vscode-vibrancy-runtime-v6'"

I've no idea why it tries to do a mkdir in this /private/ folder. And this problem also happens for the extension "Enable Custom CSS and JS" so I guess the problem is on my side.

All my extensions are installed in ~/.vscode/extensions.  And vscode itself is in ~//Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/.   (Not sure why it's not in Application)

I've tried using sudo chown -R $(whoami)  but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving VSCode to `/Applications`? This issue has been documented on the project's GitHub before, and it happens due to macOS applying ["App Translocation"](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/09/06/dont-run-that-app-where-it-landed-how-translocation-can-cause-crashes/) to any apps that are quarantined and/or not in `/Applications`, effectively rendering their folders to be read-only as seen by the application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide for trouble shooting from this vibrancy continued documentation.
After that the  https://github.com/illixion/vscode-vibrancy-continued?tab=readme-ov-file#vscode_vibrancyopacity

It says to move vscode into /applications. Vs code for some reason install in /Downloads for some mac users.

If moving vscode does not work. What worked for me was deleting vscode from my  mac and then moving it to /Applications. Once vscode in is in /Applications, follow the guide to set up by reload vibrancy or enable vibrancy.

Hope this helps